# Safari on iPhone is unable to style the color of pseudo element :after with content \2714 but it works for \2713

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I want both checkmarks to be white, but the :after element is black (however it seems to have a vertical white to black gradient).

It works in Chrome and Safari on a MacBook.

Open this example page in Safari on an iPhone to see the issue:

http://output.jsbin.com/lerudihiho/

(and here is the code: http://jsbin.com/ponamazoso/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 9 removed the possibility to change certain symbol colors using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639694/ios-9-removed-the-possibility-to-change-certain-symbol-colors-using-css)

Answer (score 20):

The fix here is similar to when you're using [U+2714 in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639694/ios-9-removed-the-possibility-to-change-certain-symbol-colors-using-css): you need to add a `U+FE0E VARIATION SELECTOR-15` directly after the check mark to tell iOS to draw it as an outline rather than a bitmap. Here's what this looks like in CSS:

```css
body::after {
  content: "\2714\fe0e";
  color: red; 
}
```

Comment: This absolutely worked for me. Thank you!