# Unicode character color issue

Tags: css, unicode

I can't change the color on the following characters:

```
<div style="font-size: 25px; color:red;">&#128269;</div>
<div style="font-size: 25px; color:red;">&#128227;</div>
```

While some other Unicode characters accept a color property:

```
<div style="font-size: 25px; color:red;">&#9881;</div>
```

Is there a way to change color on the previous characters?

https://jsfiddle.net/cs5053ka/

Comment: Works for me in Chrome Version 54.0.2840.34 beta-m (64-bit) / FF48.0.2 & IE11...is this browser specific?

Comment: First time I see that characters. But them are colored characters, I think you can't modify the color of them

Comment: @Paulie_D in my chrome doesn't work the color on the 3 elements. On firefox works the color for the third element, but not for the two first elements, that them are coloured.

Comment: Which version of Chrome and on what OS?

Comment: Chrome last, firefox last, Mac OS El Capitán

Comment: I think is typography specific

Comment: See on firefox: http://s18.postimg.org/xcjxn4mdl/Captura_de_pantalla_2016_09_22_a_las_18_11_15.png

Comment: See on chrome: http://s11.postimg.org/e00r5gy9f/Captura_de_pantalla_2016_09_22_a_las_18_12_18.png

Comment: Not on Windows,,,,looks like it's OS specific - Chrome - http://s11.postimg.org/b684o79ub/Capture.png

Comment: As you can see, at least on Mac two first elements are coloured. I think this is not solvable with css. But the third element is different on chrome and firefox on the same OS. Weird huh? Maybe a mix of SO + Typography?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent Unicode Emoji Glyphs/Symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659949/inconsistent-unicode-emoji-glyphs-symbols)

Comment: On my Linux computer, the characters are all monochrome (that is, red). I'm interested in knowing which fonts @Marcos and the OP are using to display these.

Answer (score 17):

On many systems, emoji characters like  and  are drawn differently from regular characters. While symbols like `%` are drawn by filling in a vector outline, emoji are often drawn using a full-color bitmap that doesn't respect your text color.

To change the color of an emoji character, you have a few options:

- Manually recolor the emoji in an image editor and use an `<img>` tag or CSS background image to display it.
- Use a web icon font like [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) that includes similar-looking icons. Icon fonts are drawn with vector outlines just like regular symbols, so the `color` property works on them.
- Use a [`text-shadow` hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776303/3308630) to fill the emoji with a solid color.

You can also use a [variation selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362138/3308630) to turn certain emoji into regular characters that can be recolored, but this doesn't work for  or .

Comment: Nice. I was beating my head against the wall on changing the color of a unicode PLUS sign. Changing it to a different unicode character worked. I didn't realize that some of the simple characters are bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use variation selector-15, given some codes can have a text form ([check this table](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-variants.html), extracted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413731/color-for-unicode-emoji/39776303#40061729), and [this one too](https://unicode-org.github.io/emoji/emoji/charts-15.0/emoji-list.html)). If it is the case, one can apply colors as a plain text. The trick is just to append 65038 (or xFE0E) after your Unicode character, like this:

```
<span>&#128269;&#65038;</span>   <!-- ︎ -->
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 25px;">
  <span style="color:red;">&#128269;&#65038;</span>
  <span style="color:green;">&#128269;&#65038;</span>
  <span style="color:blue;">&#128269;&#65038;</span>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 25px;">
  <span style="color:red;">&#x1F508;&#65038;</span>
  <span style="color:green;">&#x1F508;&#65038;</span>
  <span style="color:blue;">&#x1F508;&#65038;</span>
</div>
```