# A div tag style does not work for &#128078; I'm stumped

Tags: html, css

I can't understand why this simple HTML won't render as I expect. I tried Edge, Chrome and FireFox and they all render the thumbs down and thumbs up in color. I can't seem to change it's default color. Since all browsers render this the same way, I must assume this behavior is normal. I just can't find any documentation explaining why particular entities behave this way.

Is there something different about certain entities?

```
  <div style="color:black">&#128078;</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643850/unicode-character-color-issue/43420793

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each browser uses what you would call emojis such as the thumbs-up and thumbs-down icon. These are browser-based and if you wish to set up one with a different colors I suggest using font awesome. They have many icons including the thumbs-up and thumbs-down that you can alter the color of. Just Google font awesome and you will see what I'm talking about. Good luck bud

Comment: These are Unicode entities that you were using. Try font awesome and it should work across all browsers